# Nested Backticks in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a javascript injector plugin for Chrome on one of the sites that my company uses. We use a third party provided software and i've made numerous edits to it just to make it more customized to our office needs. Our office schedules surgery for patients but the software doesn't come with a module for that. So I decided to make one by scraping data from the patient's info page and inserting it into the paperwork where it needs to be.

Currently this is my process: page loads -> Scrape data from page and insert those strings into preview form (bootstrap modal) -> Once form previewed, take form values and pass to paperwork page.

In order to inject the modal html contents for the preview window, I have to use backticks to work with interpolating variables into the html contents (ex: `<h1>${patient}</h1>`). All that is working perfectly. I can pull the scraped values from the page just fine.

I also have the html for the paperwork page being generated by a document.write function on a new window. But because i'm injecting all this, I can't refer to another file, this all has to (or seems to be that way)be generated by this one stream of JS code. But I can't figure out how to nest the paperwork page within the html/script of the parent js (which has backticks) and pass all the variable information to the paperwork page.

I know this is confusing because i'm confused writing it. Essentially i'm injecting two html files into a parent page. But the second html file is a child of the first html file. Since the first one is already injected with backticks, I can't get the second one to perform since I can't have nested backticks.

I've really broken my code down here to try and communicate the best example.

```
var patient;

$(body).append(`
<input id="patient" type="text" value="Arnold S.">
<button onclick="producePaperwork()">Click here to load paperwork</button>

<script>

function producePaperwork(){
patient = $("#patient").val();
var w = window.open();
w.document.write(\`<h1>${patient}</h1>\`);
w.document.close();

}


</script>

`);
```

I've tried to escape the internal backticks as shown in my code, this produces a result of "undefined" being printed on the new page.

I've tried backticking the internal variable: `` <h1>${`patient`}</h1> `` and this just prints the literal word "patient" on the new window, not the contents of the variable.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Just go old-school: `'<h1>' + patient + '</h1>'`

Comment: The backslash-escaped backticks should work as well.

Comment: In addition to escaping those back-ticks, You would also have to escape the dollar sign: `\${patient}` should do the trick